# Field separation before awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have *file1* and *file2* of the form:

```
file1
æææøø (xxxx yyyy)
ðý??? (xx yyy zzzz)
harbour

file2
information1
information2
information3
```

that I want to combine and output as comma separated values (csv) in one single file:

```
desired output:
æææøø (xxxx yyyy),information1
ðý??? (xx yyy zzzz),information2
harbour,information3
```

However, the script I use `pr -m -t -s\  file1 file2 | awk '{print $1","$2}' > out` gives me this output:

```
wrong output:
æææøø,(xxxx
ðý???,(xx
harbour,information3
```

Guess the desired output has to do with setting the field separation (similar to `FS='\n'`) before reading in the files. But how to implement it?

Comment: Could you show us bash & paste versions ?

Answer (score 5):

It could be simpler to use `paste`, e.g.,

```
paste -d',' file1 file2
```

Here, the `-d` option specifies the desired delimiter.

Comment: You are right, but since I also have foreign characters in the files (like æ ø ð) the paste option doesn't work.

Comment: if you want just to concatenate the lines and add the delimiter then I don't see why non-ASCII characters should pose any complication...

Comment: @Eocene state in what way `the paste option doesn't work` - wrong output, no output, syntax error, core dump, something else? If the problem you are trying to solve is how to deal with foreign characters then obviously you should edit your question to include some of those in your sample input/output and explain the issues.

Comment: Since I have those foreign characters in file1 I get this error message: `paste: Error reading file1`. I've tried so many things with paste, but it doesn't work. awk, on the other hand, doesn't complain about the foreign characters.

Comment: @Eocene would be nice to see a small example for which this happens

Comment: @Eocene again, if that's the problem, then edit your question to show it. This IS the right answer to the question you asked.

Comment: Simplier and elegant.

Comment: Sorry, Ed Morton and others. Now I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: And I've posted an answer to show that paste handles that input just fine. Are you sure it's not something else? A missing newline at the end of the file, maybe? Please edit your question again: do a copy/paste to show you running `paste` on those specific input files and the output and error message you get and also tell us what OS and platform you are running on. I have a feeling no-one's going to be able to reproduce your problem from that input so I'd like to make sure you can at least!

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why it's failing for you as the solution is paste:

```
$ paste -d, file1 file2
æææøø (xxxx yyyy),information1
ðý??? (xx yyy zzzz),information2
harbour,information3
```

but if you can't get that to work for you then try this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR]","$0}' file1 file2
æææøø (xxxx yyyy),information1
ðý??? (xx yyy zzzz),information2
harbour,information3
```

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much, Ed!! I'm kind of novice to scripting, but it's really fascinating how much difference it can do. Again thank you and also thanks to the others who tried to help me through.

Comment: No seriously, I spent a lot of time yesterday trying with `paste` but no luck. Can't figure out why. Maybe some formatting issues with the foreign characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version :

```
pr --sep-string="|" -J -m -t -s\  file1 file2 | awk -F "|" '{print $1 "," $2}'
```

Results :

```
æææøø (xxxx yyyy),information1
ðý??? (xx yyy zzzz),information2
harbour,information3
```

Comment: Guess you are on the right track, but I get this error message: `pr: illegal option -- -
usage: pr [+page] [-col] [-adFfmprt] [-e[ch][gap]] [-h header]
          [-i[ch][gap]] [-l line] [-n[ch][width]] [-o offset]
          [-L locale] [-s[ch]] [-w width] [-] [file ...]`

Comment: Strange, it works on Cygwin/Bash 4.1.10... Perhaps `"--"` means it's a typo, i.e. you added an extra space between `--` and `sep-string`  ?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS bash, I copied and pasted your script and did not add any extra space.

Comment: Try `-S"|"` instead. By the way; the `paste -d` solution is better : simplier and covers all the cases (mine assume there is no `|` in `file1` ans `file2`). If it doesn"t work, try `man pr` and look for a separator option.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**. I figured out that the `paste` command actually does work if changes are made in the `LC_CTYPE` variable. My `locale` variables originally read:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

But `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` causes the script to fail on `paste`. However, if changed to "C" the script runs perfectly well:

```
$ locale
LANG=  
LC_COLLATE="C"  
LC_CTYPE="C"  
LC_MESSAGES="C"  
LC_MONETARY="C"  
LC_NUMERIC="C"  
LC_TIME="C"  
LC_ALL=
```

Upon this change,

`$ paste -d, file1 file2`

works perfectly well, even with foreign characters.